# How to heat swimming pool with physics principles

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, water, home-experiment

I'd like to apply physics principles to a home-experiment relating to my swimming pool.

The water should flow inner to 100 meters of black pipe and so it should become warm. Then it should return in the swimming pool.

But how can I carry the water from the swimming pool to the pipe? if I use a tight pipe, for the capillarity and putting the pipe vertically from the bottom of the swimming pool, the water should come up.. but it has to pass about 30 cm... is it possible to pass a similar hight using capillarity? (the pipe should be 30 cm over the water level) Which should the pipe diameter be?

If the idea is impracticable, which principle can I use?

Comment: I dont think capillary action is enough to circulate the water of the whole swimming pool. Maybe a [siphon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphon) can help.

Comment: Why not connect the black pipe to your existing pump?

Comment: look at a thermosiphon

Comment: @mart what? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosiphon ?

Comment: @KyleKanos I'd like to avoid it... I'd like to "use" Physics!  ;)

Comment: @sunrise exactly. needs for the pool to be higher than the solar collector, though.

Comment: @mart I think I haven't understood your idea. How would you "build" the system?

Comment: you connect one end of the pipe to the bottom of your swimming pool, one to to the top but below water level, and lay the pipe out in the sun. make sure there is noe air trapped in the pipe. the convection will ensure a slow flow through the pipe.

Comment: @mart, the physical location of the swimming pool will greatly affect the usablity of a thermosiphon, or any kind of siphon for that matter. If the swimming pool is on ground level, you'll have to build a trench deep enough for the heater, and you'll have to find a way to get the sunlight to it. This adds to a lot of complications!

Comment: @sunrise: so basically you want to avoid doing it the [proper way](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61pJ4eDo%2BrL._SX385_.jpg) in favor of rigging up your own (likely) cruddy contraption? I spent 5 years as a pool serviceman and had to fix issues like this; trust the professionals & do it the *right* way.

Comment: Just for completeness on the capillary action idea. 

The (simplified) formula for capillary action can be written as:
$$h=\frac{2 \gamma \cos \theta}{\rho g r} $$
where $\gamma$ is the surface tension between water and air, $\theta$ is the contact angle of the water-air interface with your pipe, $\rho$ is the density of the water, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration and $r$ is the inner diameter of the pipe under investigation.

Comment: If we now assume that you select a material for the pipe which has a contact angle $\theta=0$ (the best scenario for capillary action) and plug in the numbers for water and your desired 30 centimeters we find $r=50 \mu m$. This could be achieved by using tiny capillaries, or as mentioned by @Diamondhills, by using rope which has pores of the same order. This will, however, be completely impractical because of the volume of water that you need to displace. For this to work you will need a huge number of microengineered capillaries which is an extremely expensive solution

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of capillary action is that it requires surface tension to move the liquids along. With both ends in the pool the surface tension cannot draw the water all the way through. A siphon would work to empty the pool but the force would balance out to zero when it re-entered the pool. Simple convection might work to circulate the hot water back into the pool, but it would likely be very slow. There is a percolating water heater design that circulates its own water supply. My suggestion would be to set up this type of system using the solar energy to heat AND circulate the water.

Ok. The basic idea is that when a fluid begins to move it has an effect on the whole body of fluid. So by applying a vacuum (or sucking) one end of the hose and keeping it below the level of the surface of the pool it will gravity flow over the wall of the pool. Essentially, the hose makes an upside down u with one end in the water and one end out of the water. The initial force comes from a pump (like your lungs). The continued kinetic energy is gravitational. As the water tries to reach an equilibrium so it will continue to run until the water outside is as high as the water inside the pool or the "inside" end of the pipe is exposed to air thus breaking the siphon. So the siphon will only fill the heating coil and the return line until the water level is equal to that of the pool, approximately 30cm short of the edge of the pool.

Comment: As for passing 30 cm using capillary, this is possible. Using a nylon rope inside a pipe would easily accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain me this step? "A siphon would work to empty the pool but the force would balance out to zero when it re-entered the pool."... which force?